# Agent hesitate when choose direction?

Tags: unity, navmesh

I have script for my agent enemy where he should choose one random point and goes to it. But what he did is hesitating !

```
private NavMeshAgent mAgent;
public GameObject[] dead_point;
public float dist;
public int direction_point;

void Start()    {
    mAgent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
    player = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player");
    dead_point = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("dead_point"); // 3 points
} // end start

void enemy_dirction()    {
    farPoint = Random.Range(0, dead_point.Length);
    mAgent.destination = dead_point[farPoint].transform.position;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()    {
    dist = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, player.transform.position);
    if (dist <= 20)
    {
        mAgent.destination = player.transform.position;
    }
    else
    {
        enemy_dirction();
    }

}// end update
```

update 1,
I used this new script and solved my problem.

```
    private NavMeshAgent mAgent;
public GameObject[] dead_point;
public float dist;
public int direction_point;

void Start()    {
    mAgent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
    player = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player");
    dead_point = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("dead_point"); // 3 points
    enemy_dirction()
} // end start

void enemy_dirction()    {
    farPoint = Random.Range(0, dead_point.Length);
    mAgent.destination = dead_point[farPoint].transform.position;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()    {
    dist = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, player.transform.position);
    if (dist <= 20)
    {
        mAgent.destination = player.transform.position;
    }
    else
    {
        if (mAgent.remainingDistance <= 0.5f) {
            mAgent.destination = dead_point[farPoint].transform.position;
            print(farPoint);
        }
    }

}// end update
```

Comment: It's unclear from this edit whether your new script is a solution, or if it still has a problem you want to solve. If it still has a problem, please describe the symptoms. If it's a solution to your problem, please post it as an Answer instead, so it doesn't get confused with the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your agent is not close to the player, then you're asking it to choose a new random destination every frame.

If you want to pick one destination and stick to it for a while, you'll need to add some conditional logic to pick a new destination only sometimes, and otherwise carry on with the old one, eg:

- when you've gotten "close enough" to the last destination you picked
- when enough time has passed since the last frame when you chose a new destination
- when an event changes your character's state
- randomly, with a low probability

etc.

Comment: I  read your notes and it's working now.

Comment: If you want to share a solution, post it as an answer. Comments are not good for sharing code.

Comment: New script it's my solution. Next time I will put it in new comment. Thank you DM.